# TeraCopy error message: "Operation did not complete ... file contains a virus", yet my antivirus did not prompt me about any detected viruses

Tags: windows, file-transfer, teracopy

When I was moving a certain file, TeraCopy outputted this error message: "Target: Operation did not complete because the file contains a virus."

Screenshot:
[image]

My antivirus (avast!) did not alert me of any detected viruses while I was moving the file. I checked out its log and it hasn't detected anything. And since I haven't configured TeraCopy to 'scan' files that it is transferring, I was wondering why it sent out this error message.

Does TeraCopy have a built-in antivirus of some sort? What could be the reasons why TeraCopy sent out this error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeraCopy in all probability only reported an error message provided by windows as it's a standard windows error message.

> 0x000000E1 ERROR_VIRUS_INFECTED    Operation did not complete
>   successfully because the file contains a virus.

And windows probably got it's information from avast.

You shoud try to scan the file manually with avast and delete it if it contains a virus.

[Windows error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199%28v=prot.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Upload the file to www.virustotal.com to see which antivirus programs consider it a virus. This will probably show Avast detecting it as such, while others don't. Then report the false positive with your findings to Avast. AV company are generally pretty quick with fixing false positives so after the next couple of AV updates your problem should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I use Avast also and sometimes it does not alert me to a potentially dangerous file and I get the standard Windows message about the file containing a virus.

If you know the file is safe, open Avast then Settings>Components>File Shield>Customize>Exclusions and add the file to the Exclusions list. You can then run the file without getting the Windows virus message.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender is aggressive, and all versions of Windows past fall Creators update is quite unfriendly to "unauthorized" user-level system function programs, even when you set administrator rights.